# MySQLI Inner Join 2 Tables

Tags: php, mysql

What am I doing wrong here. I have followed many examples but can't seem to get this working.
I have 2 tables

Table => users

```
user_id
user_name
user_email
user_password
user_country
user_dobdate
user_company
user_code
user_status
user_type
```

Table => applications

```
apply_id
apply_from
apply_leave_type
apply_priority
apply_start_date
apply_end_date
apply_halfday
apply_contact
apply_reason
apply_status
apply_comment
apply_dated
apply_action_date
```

SQLI QUERY

```
$query = $db->select("SELECT users.user_id, app.apply_from FROM users INNER JOIN applications ON  users.user_id = app.apply_from WHERE users.user_code='1'");
$rows = $db->rows();
foreach ($rows as $apply){
$apply_id = $apply['apply_id'];
$apply_from = $apply['apply_from'];
```

Error Message

```
Warning: mysqli_num_rows() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli_result, boolean given in xxxxxxxxxxxxxxx line 26
```

Comment: Nope, That's not the correct answer. There's something wrong with the SQL QUERY...

Comment: where are you using mysqli_num_rows() ?

Comment: Yes. EVERY time any mysql*-function complains about not getting a resource, but a boolean, the SQL query failed and needs to be inspected. IT'S LIKE THIS EVERY TIME.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your query;

```
SELECT users.user_id, app.apply_from 
FROM users 
INNER JOIN applications 
  ON  users.user_id = app.apply_from 
WHERE users.user_code='1'
```

...uses an alias `app` for the table `application`, but does not declare it.

```
INNER JOIN applications app
```

Answer (score 3):

You have missed the alias name for table `applications` as `app` in `join`. Try the following:

```
SELECT users.user_id,app.apply_from 
FROM users 
INNER JOIN applications app ON users.user_id = app.apply_from 
WHERE users.user_code='1'
```

Answer (score 2):

Put abbreviation 'app' for `applications` table:

```
SELECT 
    users.user_id, 
    app.apply_from 
FROM
    users 
INNER JOIN
    applications AS app
ON
    users.user_id = app.apply_from
WHERE
    users.user_code='1'
```